# Assign a CSV file for the Global User Defined Variables

Tags: jmeter

How can I assign a CSV file for the Global User Defined Variables. The CSV file will hold multiple request body data for Concurrent hits. Please find the User Defined Variables screen shot attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the attached or linked image.

Comment: Paul - I have attached the screen shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) is basically a collection of [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html), so you cannot set anything but Name, Value and Description in form of [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

You can use [__fileToString() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) like:

[image: FileToString in UDV]

but you won't be able to access different columns this way.

Be aware that [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) has "Sharing mode", you can control the scope and behaviour by amending the value.

Comment: I have to read HTTP request body in BeanShell to generate a token before finally sending in Jmeter, hence I created a variable in User Defined Variable window and used as String body = vars.get("BODY_REGISTRATION") in Beanshell. How can I achieve the same with the help of CSV Data set Config.